# Newly added row to DataGridView not showing

Tags: c#, orm, datagridview, subsonic

I have a DataGridView that allows users to enter new information. Using subsonic I Save the new info to the database. And this works correctly. My problem is that after the Save is done the newly added row disappears from the grid. I tried to Reload the form, but I get the following error:

```
Operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the SetCurrentCellAddressCore function.
```

I don't think the issue is subsonic related. Does anyone know why the newly added row disappears?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason was that I broke the binding connection by using ".ToTable()"

kek444 - thanks for the reply. Don't think that will help. I'm not using _CellEndEdit but instead using _RowValidating. I've also tried _RowLeave and others. I don't really want to reload the form - I just don't know why the newly entered values disapper when the row loses focus.